# How to set selected index on RadioGroup programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

> Let's say there are many options in RadioGroup such as following.

ex:  Your answer is ...

Option 1, Option 2 ... Option N

*I wish to select a RadioButton directly without any checking values.*

Please share your any experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is my current using codes, but not sure this is perfect one...*

[image]

[image]